# The probability of more than $10$ people getting their own hat is no more than $1/100$

Tags: probability

> Use Chebyshev's inequality to show that the probability that more than $10$ people get the correct hat back when a hatcheck person returns hats at random does not exceed $1/100$ no matter how many people check their hats.

I know that $E(X)=1$, where $X$ is the number of hats returned correctly. To use Chebyshev's inequality I also need the variance $V(X)$, but I don't know how to get $V(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(X) = 1$ which we can get from summing the variances for each person and adding twice the sum of the pairwise covariances.  $11$ people getting their hat would be $10$ standard deviations above the mean of $1$, and Chebyshev says that can't happen with a probability exceeding $1/10^2 = 1/100$.

Let $X_i = 1$ when person $i$ gets there hat back, and $0$ otherwise.

$$V(X_i) = E(X_i) - [E(X_i)]^2 = P(X_i) - [P(X_i)]^2$$

$$V(X_i) = \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{N^2} = \frac{1}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)$$

$$V(X) = NV(X_i) + 2{N \choose 2}\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j), \:\:i>j$$

$$V(X) = \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) + N(N-1)\left[E(X_i,X_j) - E(X_i)E(X_j)\right], \:\:i>j$$

$E(X_i,X_j)\neq\:0$ only when $X_i = X_j = 1.$

$$V(X) = \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) + N(N-1)\left[\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N^2}\right]$$

$$V(X) = 1.$$

Here's a little R sim which will spit out the expected value and variance which will both be close to $1$ if you run it long enough and then break it.

```
N = 1000
ev = 0
var = 0
sims = 0
while(1) {
  hats = sample(1:N,N,replace=FALSE)
  s = sum(hats == 1:N)
  ev = ev + s
  var = var + s^2
  sims = sims + 1
}
ev = ev/sims
var = var/sims - ev^2
ev
var
sims
```

Output:

```
> ev
[1] 0.9991367
> var
[1] 1.006548
> sims
[1] 47492
```